# Warnings on Relay: No unused circIDs found on channel without wide circID support

Tags: relays, circuit, freebsd

I am running a Tor relay on FreeBSD 10, with OpenSSL 1.0.1 (from ports, because of more performant curves). The version is Tor version 0.2.5.4-alpha (git-d2147cc7ba5c5d51). It has a somewhat high load and I receive the following warnings throughout my log. I am not sure how to deal with these.

```
May 28 16:31:51.000 [warn] Unexpected sendme cell from client. Closing circ (window 1000).
May 28 16:35:20.000 [warn] No unused circIDs found on channel without wide circID support, with 0 inbound and 6 outbound circuits. Found 0 circuit IDs in use by circuits, and 64 with pending destroy cells.Failing a circuit.
May 28 18:51:24.000 [warn] No unused circIDs found on channel without wide circID support, with 0 inbound and 12 outbound circuits. Found 0 circuit IDs in use by circuits, and 64 with pending destroy cells.Failing a circuit.
May 28 18:51:24.000 [warn] failed to get unique circID. [7 similar message(s) suppressed in last 9600 seconds]
```

EDIT: It appears to be related to high throughput, but there is still enough CPU and memory left.

EDIT2: Also I get this:

```
void circuit_unlink_all_from_channel(channel_t *, int)(): Bug: Circuit on detached list which I had no reason to mark
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug. Actually two bugs:

https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/12184